# Passport stamp on exit of Schengen to Schengen as a non EU citizen

Tags: visas, schengen, passport-stamps

As a resident of Chile on holiday in Sweden (90 days tourist no visa required), will I get a passport stamp upon leaving Sweden even though the flight is to another Schengen country, say France or Spain?

Comment: Why do you need a exit stamp? Is there any reason for that?

Comment: It has to do with an application for recidency. The Migration Agency requires proof in the form of a stamp in the passport, to show we are not in the country when the decision of residency is taken.

Answer (score 6):

No, you will not pass through the systematic passport check when flying between Schengen countries, and you will not get passport stamps at either end of the flights.

In some, more-or-less exceptional, situation you may encounter "extraordinary" passport checks in or between the Schengen countries. Even if you run into such a check, you are **not crossing the external Schengen border**, so you wont't get a stamp (falsely) claiming you have done so.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Flights between Schengen countries are regarded as domestic flights, so there will not be any stamp. In fact, you may even not be controlled at all.